# Do Ganondorf's Steed, and Zelda's Steed have names?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, legend-of-zelda-series

Throughout the LoZ Series, Ganondorf's and Zelda's horses make multiple appearances. Likely the most evident is in Ocarina of Time.

In breath of the Wild, the horses can be found, tamed, and even named.

From doing some research, these horses do not appear to actually have names, that I have been able to find, simply being called "Royal Steed" and "Ganondorf's Steed" or "Giant Horse".

Since these are somewhat iconic steeds, I figured that it would be likely that they should have names, like Epona does. Is this the case? Do they actually have names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Directly stated in the games, no. The horses don't have any names.

However, outside of the games, they kind of have names. There's a white steed named Storm that Zelda rides in the Valiant Comics that's very similar to the in-game horse that Zelda and Impa ride out of Hyrule Castle, although the comics are mostly independent works with no relationship to the games. From the [wiki](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Storm):

> Storm is the name of a large, white horse which belongs to Princess Zelda, as seen in the Valiant Comics. Storm helps Zelda leave Hyrule's North Palace when she attempts to leave Hyrule in order to keep the Triforce of Wisdom from the reach of Ganon.

Ganondorf's horse name is a little trickier. I've seen numerous unproven citations that the horse's name is Galloughs ranging from GameFAQs posts to Reddit posts to DeviantArt fanfiction, feel free to google the name yourself, and the most consistent proof I can find is that multiple people seem to think the Ganondorf horse object in OoT's code is named Galloughs. However, looking at multiple object lists [here](https://wiki.cloudmodding.com/oot/Actor_List_(Variables)) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/flotonic65/modding/n64zeldadoc/debugzobjdoc), the horse is just referred to as Ganon's Horse or something equally uninteresting, and the dataminers of [The Cutting Room Floor](https://tcrf.net/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time) haven't made mention of any horse-related discoveries, so I'm personally skeptical.

Answer (score 0):

Zelda's horse name is Storm which can be seen in the comics. Ganon's horse name is Phantom which is also in the comics.

Comment: "The comics"... which comics? I'm sure if I googled Legend of Zelda comics, I'd get thousands of results.

Comment: @zigg in a case like this I think it would be okay to just write a new answer. This one is very old, the user hasn't been active, and you're improving their answer *a lot* by giving references.